# PHP Websocket Performance

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, websocket, ratchet

I am using PHP and websocket to create a group chat application to be available on web and mobile. I've used the sample code from this tutorial: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

Now, I just want to get some insights if how this app can perform under thousands of connections (1k, 5k, 10k, 50k, 100k) considering that messages will be saved in a MySQL database.

I know Ratchet and NodeJS can do the job, but I want my code to stay simple as possible.

My question is, is the code available in the said tutorial is scalable enough to handle thousands of connection? If not, how can I improve it? Can I add additional websocket connections using the same code for the notifications and offline/online status checking?

Thanks

Comment: So? What exactly is your question?

Comment: depends on your server maybe?